# Writing and Printing an extra 0 to sorted files and cutting node (singly linked list)off the end C++

Tags: c++, sorting, file-io, singly-linked-list

That may seem kind of vague so really sorry. I am writing to a file and printing to a console the sorted nodes in this singly linked list. Unfortunately, in the sort list, it both prints and writes an extra 0 at the front and cuts a value off the end. Here is the code:

```
void SLLIntStorage::Read(istream& r)
{
    char c[13];
    r >> c;
    r >> numberOfInts;

    head = new Node;
    head->next = NULL;
    tail = head;
    r >> head->data;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfInts; i++)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node;
        r >> newNode->data;

        if(_sortRead)
        {
            if(newNode->data > tail->data)
            {
                tail->next = newNode;
                tail = newNode;
            }
            else if(head->data > newNode->data)
            {
                newNode->next = head;
                head = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                current = head;

                while(current->next != NULL)
                {
                    if(current->next->data > newNode->data)
                    {
                        newNode->next = current->next;
                        current->next = newNode;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        current = current->next;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
    }
    print();
}

void SLLIntStorage::Write(ostream& w)
{
    current = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfInts; i++)
    {
        w << current->data << endl;

        if (current->next != NULL)
            current = current->next;
    }
}
void SLLIntStorage::print()
{
    current = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfInts; i++)
    {
        cout << current->data << endl;
        //system("pause");
        if(current->next != NULL)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}
```

**File sample:**
0
0
1
2
2
3
........
9995
9996
9996
9998
*//supposed to be another 9998 here*

Comment: FIXED - I did i = 1 on all the for loops and on the print and write methods for looks i did numberOfInts + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you read one entry too much. You first read an entry in the line `r >> head->data;`
 just before the `for`-loop. Then you read an additional `numberOfInts` entries in the `for`-loop for a total of `numberOfInts+1` entries.